# Browsersync "browser" option in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, browser, browser-sync

I have browsersync on Ubuntu 16.04, I want to init it in the Chromium.
I have this in my gulpfile:

```
browserSync.init({
  server:"./project",
  browser:"chromium"
});
```

When I starting browserSync I have this error: "Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set open option to false).

But if I delete this line: `browser:"chromium"` it starting perfectly with Firefox and works OK. So how I need to change: `browser:"chromium"` to start it in Chromium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: `browser:"chromium-browser"`